# Fantasy/sci-fi cartoon with 4 "guardian" characters with animals determining their powers, one merges with his animal into a monster

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I don’t remember much about it but it was like a system where the children all inherit their powers from their parents. They were all guardians and had a special animal/dinosaur as a pet that determined their powers.

- One was a guy who I think had rocks/lava power. He had dark hair. He eventually turned sort of evil at the end because he believed he was a monster due to permanently merging with his “animal” and couldn’t switch back to human form.
- One was a girl that was ice power had white hair and wore blue. Her “animal” was a flying tiny dinosaur
- The others were a brother and sister, the sister couldn’t walk so the brother always worried about her but she was super strong I think.

Comment: Avatar: The Last Airbender?

Comment: No but the drawing style is similar though

Comment: If the sister couldn't walk, how did she get around?

Comment: She got around using a wheelchair and she had special boots later on in the show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is the 2006 show [*Di-Gata Defenders*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/DiGataDefenders).

[image: cartoon still, featuring the five main teen characters]

It revolves around a group of kids that are part of the Di-Gata Defenders and they use special rocks that have the power to call upon the Primordial beings (aka animal/dinosaurs) to fight with them. The main character starts to merge with his animal and is thinking of himself as a monster until someone helps him. One girl is unable to walk and has to use special boots and is always helped by her big brother.